# How to make efficient movement handling

Tags: java, processing, game-engine

I am developing a "game engine" (with Processing's core.jar as a library) to use for a future game, and have got some basic structure setup, however I have tried testing creating a moving player and realized that the movement handling I have created is embarrassing and it also doesn't function perfectly. For example, the diagonal speed is just a guess, and the whole thing is just feels unnecessarily bloated.

```
@Override
public void update(Entity entity, double delta)
{
    if (movingLeft && movingUp && movingRight)
    {
        entity.setY((entity.getY() - 3.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingUp && movingRight && movingDown)
    {
        entity.setX((entity.getX() + 3.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingRight && movingDown && movingLeft)
    {
        entity.setY((entity.getY() + 3.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingDown && movingLeft && movingUp)
    {
        entity.setX((entity.getX() - 3.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingUp && movingRight)
    {
        entity.setX((entity.getX() + 2.0f) * (float) delta);
        entity.setY((entity.getY() - 2.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingRight && movingDown)
    {
        entity.setX((entity.getX() + 2.0f) * (float) delta);
        entity.setY((entity.getY() + 2.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingDown && movingLeft)
    {
        entity.setX((entity.getX() - 2.0f) * (float) delta);
        entity.setY((entity.getY() + 2.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingLeft && movingUp)
    {
        entity.setX((entity.getX() - 2.0f) * (float) delta);
        entity.setY((entity.getY() - 2.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingUp)
    {
        entity.setY((entity.getY() - 3.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingRight)
    {
        entity.setX((entity.getX() + 3.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingDown)
    {
        entity.setY((entity.getY() + 3.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
    else if (movingLeft)
    {
        entity.setX((entity.getX() - 3.0f) * (float) delta);
    }
}
```

How could I optimize this? It would be useful if I knew how to create a better movement system for the future when I do create a game, especially since I already have an idea in mind and want to start working with this engine as soon as it is "usable enough" to start my game.

Comment: I would recommend reading this free online book: [The Nature of Code](https://natureofcode.com/book/)

Comment: Are you moving from and to a known positions (think projectile) or are you moving based on angle of direction?  This does kind of come down to the same problem, but the implementation will change.  Also, are you moving at a constant speed (ie while a key is pressed) or over a period of time?

Comment: There is a method keyPressed() that checks what the key is, and enables the moving booleans according to the key. When a key is released, it is checked for and if it's respective movement boolean is true, the boolean is set to false. I want my character to be able to move freely in all directions, including diagonally if multiple keys are pressed. Before I did have it so each direction had an isolated if statement which made it allow diagonal movement, but it moved the speed it would move in a straight line on both axes.

Comment: I don't get it what is happening when `movingLeft && movingUp && movingRight` is true? It reads like the entity is both moving left and right. So those cancel out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating 2 direction variables for X and Y?

```
public void update(Entity entity, double delta) {
    int directionX = 0;
    int directionY = 0;

    if (movingLeft) directionX -= 1;
    if (movingRight) directionX += 1;
    if (movingUp) directionY -= 1;
    if (movingDown) directionY += 1;

    if (directionX != 0 && directionY != 0) {
        // move in both direction
        entity.setX((entity.getX() + 2.0f * directionX) * (float) delta);
        entity.setY((entity.getY() + 2.0f * directionY) * (float) delta);
        return;
    }

    // move in one direction or not moving
    entity.setY((entity.getY() + 3.0f * directionY) * (float) delta);
    entity.setX((entity.getX() + 3.0f * directionX) * (float) delta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not far away from a working solution with your code. You simply have to remove your `else if` parts and focus on the four fundamental directions:

```
if (movingLeft)
{
   entity.setX((entity.getX() - 3.0f) * (float) delta);
}
if (movingRight)
{
   entity.setX((entity.getX() + 3.0f) * (float) delta);
}
if (movingUp)
{
   entity.setY((entity.getY() - 3.0f) * (float) delta);
}
if (movingDown)
{
   entity.setY((entity.getY() + 3.0f) * (float) delta);
}
```

(I am assuming here that your variables `movingLeft` etc. are true for as long as the respective key is held down. Also the movement code inside the if's is just a guess.)

The difference to your code is that multiple of the if's can now be executed, whereas in your code only one of the if branches could be executed (because of `else if`). Therefore, you do not need to list all the possible combinations. Now your objects should also be able to move diagonally.

Comment: Yes I had this before and it works well, the only issue is that it moves faster diagonally.